# Where is Android SDK manager download files?

Tags: catalina, android

Actually, I installed Android Studio on my MacBook Pro and then requested the SDKs from the SDK manager of Android Studio. I set downloads and then abandoned the MacBook Pro in the office and now I see all downloads failed.

So I wanna find all downloaded packages or corrupted downloaded files or partially downloaded files and delete them.

*Where does the Android Studio SDK manager download its files?*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996642/how-do-i-find-android-sdk-manager-path-on-mac

Comment: @ankii, thanks, but I didn't want to find the SDK path, I wanna know where the Android Studio download the SDKs.

Answer (score 2):

> In Android Studio, open the Settings dialog (Preferences on macOS), then navigate to Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK.
>   Change the value of Android SDK Location to C:\WorkFolder\AndroidSDK.
>
> To avoid downloading the SDK again, make sure to copy the existing SDK directory, located at %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\SDK by default, to the new location.

From https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#antivirus-impact

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I don't understand.